# Re-Displaying Facebook Data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

Suppose user A gives access permission to all of their FB data to my site.

Suppose user B comes to my site and tries to view user B's info.

Scenario #1:
Suppose I store all of user A's FB data (with user A's permission of course).
What can user B see of User A's data? Only public info?

Scenario #2:
Suppose I do not store user A's FB data, although user A has granted full permission to their FB data.
What can user B see of user A's data? I'm guessing if user B is logged in to FB, then they would see the same amount of data as when they are on facebook.com?

Answer (score 0):

For both scenarios the same functionality:

1-User A gives to your site some permissions (picture, profile info, post messages... and/or **offline privileges**)

2-If your site has offline privileges, you can get the user A data at any moment and show it to whoever you want

3-If you don't have offline privileges you can get the user A data when he is connected and show it to whoever you want

The other option is to store the user A data whenever he connects and show it (not updated) to the user N when he connects to your site.

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Comment: How do I request for offline privileges? Also, are there any additional terms of service requirements/limits? I recall there being one about not allowing for social networks to get this data from users?

Comment: Also, if user B is logged in to FB, and comes to my site to look at user A's info, would user B's rights be applied automatically?

For instance, suppose user B has permission to view user A's private photo album "Family".

Comment: It always depends on the permissions your app has with the user. In the case the user granted you all permissions, you would see everything the user can see. There is more information here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/